# How to produce a "broken gif" effect - video example

Tags: effects, special-effects, distortion

I am interested in gathering opinons on the best way to create an effect very similar to what might be termed "Broken gif". In this effect the last still shot of the previous scene is used as the colour values for the next one, but all the motion and changes are already unrelated to the depth and other information of that last scene.

Here is a video which makes pretty good use of the effect.

Comment: It does look like a duplicate to me as well.